# Angularjs passing multiple inputs from HTML to controller using one ng-model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, controller

So I have some input text boxes in my html which I would like to send into my controller and add them to an object. What confuses me is how do I pass more than one value using only one ng-model. So far this is what I have in my html that reads out the number of inputs needed:

```
<div ng-repeat = "parameter in selectedMO.parameters">
   <label> Value for {{parameter.name}} </label>
   <input type="text" ngmodel="value"/>
</div>
```

Since I am using ng-repeat to add the necessary number of text boxes I only have one ng-model instead of different ones for every value.

```
angular.module('app.runBehaviorOper', [])
   .controller('runBehaviorOper', [ 'discoveryService','$scope', '$route',  
      function( discoveryService, $scope, $route) {

     //what should I do here in order to add each value inputted into 
     //an object in order to then be able to send it a function inside 
     //my discoveryService file

     $scope.getBehaviorExec = function() { //this is called with the submit
      // button in the html code

        discoveryService.getBehaviorExec({ 
           oid:              $scope.oid,
           parameters:       //send parameters

        });

     };

  }
]);
```

I am quite new to angularjs and the answers online have not worked so far for me.

Comment: ngmodel="value[$index]"  This should give you an array of values.  $index is created by ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'll want to take advantage of `track by $index` with regards to `ngRepeat` and then associating the value with an `array` defined on `$scope`.

Your code blocks could end up looking like:

```
<div ng-repeat = "parameter in selectedMO.parameters track by $index">
   <label> Value for {{parameter.name}} </label>
   <input type="text" ng-model="values[$index]"/>
</div>
```

NOTE: I changed `ngmodel="value"` to `ng-model="values[$index]"`

Then within your controller:

```
angular.module('app.runBehaviorOper', [])
   .controller('runBehaviorOper', [ 'discoveryService','$scope', '$route',  
      function( discoveryService, $scope, $route) {

     $scope.values = []; // This will contain all the input values

     $scope.getBehaviorExec = function() { //this is called with the submit
      // button in the html code

        discoveryService.getBehaviorExec({ 
           oid:              $scope.oid,
           parameters:       $scope.values // I'm assuming this is where you would use the various input values

        });

     };

  }
]);
```

Hope that works for you!

Solution the second:

Another approach (and probably cleaner), would be to utilize the same object you are iterating through:

```
<div ng-repeat = "parameter in selectedMO.parameters">
   <label> Value for {{parameter.name}} </label>
   <input type="text" ng-model="parameter.value"/>
</div>
```

Then within your controller:

```
angular.module('app.runBehaviorOper', [])
   .controller('runBehaviorOper', [ 'discoveryService','$scope', '$route',  
      function( discoveryService, $scope, $route) {

     $scope.getBehaviorExec = function() { //this is called with the submit
      // button in the html code

        discoveryService.getBehaviorExec({ 
           oid:              $scope.oid,
           parameters:       $scope.selectedMO.parameters // you will still need to access each $scope.selectedMO.parameters value since the parameters is now not just an array of input values

        });

     };

  }
]);
```

Give that the ol' college try - but it should work for you!  And as you can see, it's a *teeny* bit cleaner!

Comment: @SantiagoEsquivel - Here's a real quick and very simple plnkr I put together to hopefully demonstrate how it would work: http://plnkr.co/edit/sjPdV313dCeR5DGW72tS?p=preview

Comment: This works, thank you, I knew it was a simple solution I just was not sure how execute it, also is it possible to add the values to an object with the fields of value and parameter.name instead of using an array?

Comment: @SantiagoEsquivel - Check out the edit I threw up there.  You are most correct that there doesn't need to be the array.  And actually, associating the value with each iterated `parameter` object is most likely a better standard to follow.  I've also updated the plnkr to display your requested changes!

Comment: I thank you very much for the detailed response and followup.